# Пример цикла на FASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Нужен простой  пример цикла на Fasm с пояснениями

Answer (score 3):

Вот так подойдет? Или более подробно надо?

```
mov cx, 20 ; число итераций
metka:
;
; действия в цикле
;
loop metka ; Команда цикла, переход на новый виток
```

Вот [тут](http://asmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/013-cikly-i-komanda-loop/) все подробно расписано.

Comment: На конкретном примере желательно, вывести от 1 до 20 например

Comment: а где mov cx, 20

Comment: Щас домой приду - поменяю - с работы ухожу как раз

Comment: @Dejsving, я добавил.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
mov cx, 10 ; кол-во повторений
loop: ; метка
    dec cx ; декремент cx
    ; любые действия где cx итерация (обратная)
    jcxz end ;если cx == 0 то перепрыгнуть
    jmp loop ;Иначе продолжить цикл
end:
    ;конец цикла
```

Comment: `dec cx` - вроде есть возможность без этого декриментить и прыгать? Да, точно, в соседнем ответе написали.

Comment: Ну только если loop использовать.

Comment: А почему бы его не использовать?

Comment: Просто как вариант )

Comment: @Qwertiy, `loop` позволяет делать прыжок только на +- 127 байт, поэтому он не всегда применим. Плюс, современные компиляторы практически не генерируют код с использованием `loop`, я предполагаю что вариант просто с условиями и джампами быстрее.

Comment: наверное у loop больше тактов процессора.

Answer (score -1):

В фасме есть два вида циклов, `.while` и `.repeat`.

```
.while al=1
 ; код
.endw
```

и

```
.repeat
  add ecx,2
.until ecx>100
```

Полный синтаксис описан в документации в разделе "3.2.2 Structuring the source".